# MySQL: I have a table say SLOT which has two column DATE and TIME, I want to populate the data in tabular form in html

Tags: mysql, laravel

MySQL Table has following structure like:

```
id, date, time
```

there maybe several time for same date for eg:

```
1, 20-10-1992, 08:00
2, 20-10-1992, 09:00
3, 20-10-1992, 10:00
4, 20-11-1992, 08:00
5, 20-11-1992, 09:00
6, 20-11-1992, 10:00
7, 20-12-1992, 08:00
8, 20-12-1992, 09:00
9, 20-12-1992, 10:00
```

I want to tabulate the data in HTML with DATE being Header and col/row being TIME using the Laravel framework so the templating is in blade.

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema such that date and time are a single entity - and (obviously) stored using a proper datetime data type

Comment: so if I have a DateTime or timestamp datatype how do I separate the two the issue will be quite the same even after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prepare one multidimensional array which has `date` group and the `date` group will have `time` group array.

```
$results = \DB::table('SLOT')->select('*')->get();
$data = [];

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $data[$result->date][$result->time][] = $result;
}
```

Send the $data to your view file and process as below

```
@foreach($data as $date => $dt)
    //your <ul> or <div> or container
    //$date
    @foreach($dt as $time => $details)
    //$time
        @foreach($details as $detail)
            {{$detail->id}}
            //put <li> or something related to your design
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: What I wanted was in a  HTML table <table> with headers as date and row as different time

Comment: @user3087836 Can you provide a wireframe if possible?

Comment: any online tool for wireframing ?

Comment: @SharadMishra check [this](https://eval.in/1062106). Hope this can help.